# Implementing getline for my custom string class

Tags: c++

I'm trying to implement a getline method for my string class that will get the line from a datafile until the deliminator is reached. My IDE is giving me an error that says no matching function.

I've tried switching the type from ifstream to fstream or istream which didn't change anything.

My getline function:

```
ifstream& getline(ifstream &is,myString& s,char& delim)
{
    char *c=new char[500];
    is.get(c,500);
     int i=0;
    while(c[i-1]!=delim)
    {
        is.get(c,500);
        s+=c;
    }
    delete[]c;
    return is;
}
```

My main:

```
int main(int argc, char*argv[])
{
    myString str;



ifstream DataFile(NULL);
cout << "AFF: " << argv[1] << endl;
cout<<"AFF: "<<argv[2]<<endl;
DataFile.open(argv[1]);
if(!DataFile)
{
    cout<<"File not found"<<endl;
}
DataFile.getline(DataFile,str,',');


cout<<str<<endl;


}
```

I cannot use the stl string class, and I need to read in files deliminated by a , or a /n. I'm constructing this method so I can parse through datafiles and put information in a vector

Comment: First you define a `getline` _free function_, but then you invoke the `getline` _method_... Also, the implementation of your `getline` is so full of errors I don't even know where to start...

Comment: "*I cannot use the stl string class*" - why not? You are using the STL `std::ifstream` and `std::vector` classes, so what is the issue if you use `std::string`, too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getline` is not a member of `std::ifstream`, so don't invoke it on `DataFile`.

```
DataFile.getline(DataFile,str,',');
```

becomes

```
getline(DataFile,str,',');
```

In addition, passing in a reference to a character literal isn't such a good idea Doesn't compile - tries to strip `const`ness) so

```
ifstream& getline(ifstream &is,myString& s,char& delim)
```

needs to become

```
ifstream& getline(ifstream &is,myString& s, const char & delim)
```

or

```
ifstream& getline(ifstream &is,myString& s, char delim)
```

since passing a reference to a `char` doesn't really gain much.

Remy Lebeau makes the point in the comments that what you really want to do is open up your `getline` to handling ANY standard input stream with

```
istream& getline(istream &is,myString& s, char delim)
```

That takes care of the question as aksed, but please note that there are several logic errors (`c[i-1]` immediately after setting `i` to zero jumps right out at me) in the implementation of `getline` that may lead to a future question or two. I recommend a [chat with the Rubber Duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) and using [your development environment's debugger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugger) to clean up the rest before asking them.

Comment: I fixed some of the logic errors, but if I'm changing the trpe to fstream and keeping the parameter as ifstream won't that produce an incompatible type error?

Comment: `getline()` really should be taking and returning an `std::istream&`, not an `std::ifstream&` or `std::fstream&`, and definitely should not be unconditionally reading 500 character at a time.

Comment: @JacobBarcelona That is a typo on my part. I meant `ifstream`. That said, Remy's correct. This function  becomes much more versatile if it accepts and returns the base class of `istream`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Should it just be getting 1 char a loop? Also if it returns istream, is there a way to use it for text files that you take in. .open() will only work for fstream.

Comment: @JacobBarcelona worst case, you *could* read 1 char at a time, yes. Though, it would be more efficient to utilize the overload of `std::istream::get()` or `std::istream::getline()` that takes a `delim` parameter as input (you are calling an overload of `get()` without that parameter). Also, `std::ifstream()` derives from `std::istream`, so you can pass a `std::ifstream` object where a `std::istream&` is taken. There is a reason why standard `operator>>` implementations take only `std::istream` to read from all kinds of input streams.